# Сжатие данных файла. Аналог формата parquet для работы в excel

Tags: python, excel

Есть массив данных, обрабатываемый в Python, при выводе в csv формат вес файла 20гб. Применить формат parquet для сжатия данных в данной ситуации не подходит, так как после обработки в python файл должен попадать в Excel и далее с ним ведется работа в power pivot. (Не BI система, именно excel) Есть ли аналог формата parquet для сжатия данных, который поддерживается excel? Или, возможно, обходные пути подключения parquet к excel? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Короткий ответ: нет и нет.